# Как работает #define, какой тип данных хранит или как его определяет?

Tags: c

Вопрос по коду из книги Брайана Кернигана и Денниса Ритчи, глава 1.4. Именованные константы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOWER 0 /* нижняя граница таблицы */
#define UPPER 300 /* верхняя граница */
#define STEP 20 /* размер шага */
/* печать таблицы температур по Фаренгейту и Цельсию */
main ()
{
 int fahr;
 for (fahr = LOWER; fahr <= UPPER; fahr = fahr + STEP)
 printf ("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
}
```

Какой тип данных хранит #define или как оно его определяет? Просто в printf в данном случае понятно, что сначала выводится целое число, а потом число флоатное, которое является результатом уравнения. Мне не понятно каким образом оно может посчитать данное уравнение, если тип данных переменной farh, которая в нём находится, по моему, не определён? И как всё это связано с #define ? У меня есть предположение по этому поводу, но они не очень ясные и вообще хотелось услышать конкретное пояснение.

Comment: Работа препроцессора в этой книжке описывается в главе 4.

Answer (score 5):

#define хранит не какие-то типизированные данные, а просто пару "имя-значение". Перед компиляцией все "имена" заменяются на "значения".

Дальше всё делает компилятор так, как будто никаких дефайнов и не было, а с самого начала текст был написан с использованием значений, определенных в #define.

В общем, #define - это тупая подстановка определенного в #define значения вместо определенного в #define же имени по всему коду. Отсюда следует, что вообще в #define можно запихнуть любую дичь, и пример #define true false - это еще довольно невинный пример.

Также, важно понимать, что подстановкой дефайнов занимается не компилятор, а препроцессор. И у него интеллекта при этом не больше, чем у функции replace(). То есть он тупо заменяет всё по тексту.

Использовать это можно, к примеру, так:

```
    #define myint unsigned long long;
    myint a = 1099511627776;
```

ведь правда, писать myint вместо unsigned long long - короче?

А еще в комментариях любезно подсказывают: "Чтобы понять зачем #define нужен, посмотрите сначала про #ifdef. Эта команда очень нужна для компилирования на разные архитектуры процессоров/операционных систем". Вот это - настоящее, а не учебное использование дефайнов.

Comment: окей, а как тогда оно уравнение считает, елси farh это строка?(оно же преобразует в флоат уже после подсчёта).

Comment: fahr это целое число

Comment: а, точно)))))))

Comment: хорошо, а как тогда оно считает fahr = fahr + STEP , если step - это строка?

Comment: STEP это число 20, а никакая не строка.

Comment: окей, тогда может вы объясните про #define ? потому что человек выше пишет, что "Оно хранит не данные, а просто пару "имя-строка". Перед компиляцией все имена заменяются на строки."

Comment: Смотрите, как это понять. Возьмите бумагу. Или распечатку программы. Везде замените STEP на 20 и т.п. Не вникая в смысл. Препроцессор же не вникает. У Вас получится программа, в котрой define'ов нет, а есть программа в которой на местах символических имен стоят конкретные значения.

Comment: В общем, define - это тупая подстановка опеределнного в define значения вместо определенного в define же имени по всему коду. Отсюда следует, что вообще в define можно запихнуть любую дичь, и пример #define true false - это еще доольно невинный пример

Comment: в общем получается всё, как и изначально мной предполагалось. а именно: объявление в дефайне это почти тоже самое, что объявить переменную(только в случае дефайна - константу) без int, float. и т.д., а оно уже само определит, что это. то есть, если в переменной/константе только цифры, оно определит как число, в остальных же случаях как строку. так получается?

Comment: я ещё правда про символ забыл и т.д.

Comment: в общем ладно, вывод один: или я тупой или дефайн это параша.

Comment: Не совсем так: "объявление в дефайне это почти тоже самое, что объявить переменную". Нет. В дефайне написано "везде по тексту программы сначала замени так.как написано в дефайне. Без поппыток придать этому смысл. Когда везде заменишь- компилируй"

Comment: Надо вместо "строки" было написать "литералы", а так ещё больше запутался автор вопроса ))

Comment: Справедливая критика, пошел исправлять

Comment: @CrazyElf, литералы тоже не очень звучит :) потому что указать можно что угодно

Comment: Чтобы понять зачем `#define` нужен, посмотрите сначала про `#ifdef`. Эта команда очень нужна для компилирования на разные архитектуры процессоров/операционных систем.